# [Power Automate - How can I create a flow "When an email is flagged in a shared mailbox."

Tags: power-automate

There is a template available to create a flow which connect your personal Outlook inbox when an email is flagged but I need the same flow to run on shared mail box. Please help me with the same. Attached is the flow which I had created

[image: When an email is flagged flow]

The flow goes in a way

- When an emails is flagged
- Create a task in Planner and Update the row in a Excel

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the trigger **When a new email arrives in a shred mailbox (V2)**, and not **When an email is flagged**. But, *unfortunately*, there is no option to detect flagged message.

The connection used by this connector must a member of the shared mailbox.

Same for creating a task in Planner: the user must be part of Planner team.

[image: When a new email arrives in a shred mailbox (V2)]

Comment: I tried using When an email is arrived in a shared mailbox but after that how the flow should be? because If i use this I understood I am using shared mailbox but then what should be the trigger for when an email is flagged

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible.